# Nautilus doesn't generate thumbnails when account is admin on Ubuntu 22.4.1

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

When I browse this folder:

> admin:////usr/share/backgrounds/

I can't see any thumbnail for .png/.jpg files there, but when using my normal acc it works ok.
Also how to generate thumbnails on remote locations, like VirtualBox shared folder ?

Comment: @David This here concerns using the `admin://..." URI to do root operations. Indeed, there is no thumbnail generation this way.

Comment: Please limit a question to a single question. Feel free to post another question if you have more than one.

Comment: @vanadium thanks